# Unable to download any image in Windows16 docker

Tags: windows, iis, docker, cmd, installation

I have been experimenting with docker the aim is

1. Install docker on windows 16
   for which I am following instructions from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server

everything looks fine till installation of the docker , after that when I try to test the docker it give

below error.

failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\0c9
effd422805350acb1f051eb171399678aff003192c41be274acc4762b786c: The system cannot find the path specified.

here I am just trying to pull "hello-world" from docker hub

My ultimate aim is to run IIS on docker container and deploy the application running on IIS.

Had anyone faced such issue or could come up with any suggestions

its VM machine with

OS :- Win2016
HDD :- 50GB
RAM :- 4GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pull the hello-world image from docker hub because it's linux image. I used to see it before while playing with Docker Container on windows when trying to do the same thing.
If you want to get different image like IIS, just run command follow the instructions:
First:

> Install-PackageProvider ContainerImage -Force

Then

> Install-ContainerImage -Name WindowsServerCore

After that, restart your docker container with

> Restart-Service docker

And you'll have the images of IIS on your machine. 
I've tried to get the images of windows as the way we do in Linux but it always throw error as you have, I guess that all images we have on hub now are for Linux only, so if you want to have particular things, you must build it by yourselves or using existed images for Windows on Docker hub (about 9 or 10 images as I remember).

Comment: Thanks huy for your reply.  The problem I am facing here is on windows 7 I have installed docker and it does pull the hello world image as it just creates a linux environment to run the docker on windows and image runs fine.

Comment: so I am unable to run  it on windows 7.................I then installed windows 16 and did ran the above commands you specified but after the     **WindowsServerCore** download is complete the error is "docker is not fully compatible we are working to get it compatible with this version** and nothing happens..............this is very strange as  the instructions are on the official sites and still not working

Comment: I've use windows 16 TP5 too. Do you run all of these command using Administrator privileges, in my case, I must run power shell with "run as administrator" option. If it doesn't work, I think may be you can restart your service and after that redo above step diligently.
P/S: I spent about 4 hours just for setup these things at first

Comment: you got IIS running finally ??

Comment: Yes, I even can deploy several things to it and build new containers for me at last :). Is it ok with you now? Any other symtomps?

Comment: Hi, I tried nano server container...it gives me below error PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-ContainerImage -Name NanoServer -Version 10.0.14300.1016
WARNING: Based on customer feedback, we are updating the Containers PowerShell module to better align with Docker. As part of that some cmdlet and parameter names may change in future
releases. To learn more about these changes as well as to join in the design process or provide usage feedback please refer to http://aka.ms/windowscontainers/powershell  and no image is shows while using docker images

Comment: Looks good for me now...will try and deploy IIS application on it now...let me know if you have any valuable resources .  Thanks I have marked this as correct answer.

Comment: How to move the application files and folders inside docker webroot...like I want to run the IIS application inside docker ...please guide

Comment: Just use docker CLI to do it, it like:
docker cp [file path on your machine] [containerId]:[path on container]
If you just deploy normal website (html only), then you can run with default IIS of container, if not, you must follow this site http://blog.asteropesystems.com/post/windows-server-2016-containers-deploy-an-mvc-web-application-into-a-container.
About the IIS, you should check this for work with IIS by CLI: http://tecadmin.net/create-website-and-apppool-in-iis-using-appcmd/#
Have a nice time with it :)

Comment: I don't get, why isn't possibile to run a linux container inside windows engine? They are doing it right with Windows 10 and Hyper-V (I see a MobyLinuxVM in Hyper-V Manager) but not with Windows Server 2016, anyone known why?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because there's no `hello-world` image for Windows. You can try running `docker run windowsservercore cmd /C hello world`.

Comment: Thanks friism.... you are right we need to run only windows images provided by docker ...cant run linux images on windows containers.